$[[10, 2, 2]]$ codes with transversal T gates
There is a 10-to-2 magic distillation protocols for the $T$ state based on the four-qubit codes (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4221). As the protocol has order-2 distillation efficiency, we can use a $[[10,2,2]]$ stabilizer code to represent the protocol (See Tab. I Box 2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07330).
I am wondering if we can derive the stabilizer generators of the $[[10, 2, 2]]$ code based on information from the original protocol paper, where they didn't explicitly mention the 10-qubit code.
Besides, as we use codes with transversal T gates for magic distillation, does this imply that the $[[10, 2, 2]]$ code has transversal T gates as it can distill the T states with quadratic efficiency?

Not all magic state distillation factories come from transversal T gates. The existence of a factory with certain parameters doesn't imply the existence of a corresponding stabilizer code with those same parameters.
The [[10,2,2]] factory in particular has no corresponding code, because the T gates that it applies don't commute with each other. The T gates need to commute to correspond to a transversal T gate because the physical T gates making up a transversal T all apply to different qubits and therefore would trivially commute. But the T gates on the left of the [[10,2,2]] factory circuit don't commute with some of the T gates on the right:


I found the $[[10, 2, 2]]$ code is explicitly written in my second reference and I would rather believe the code exists. I also don't understand your circuit here because for a $[[n, k, d]]$ protocol, you start with the tensor product of faulty input magic states. You need to move every in-circuit T gate in a form of a T state with a state injection circuit.

@Yunzhe What do you mean it is explicitly written? They have the text "[[10,2,2]]" but that's not a code. I don't see a definition of a code for it. They're just saying 10 T states turn into 2 with quadratic suppression. And you can easily change my circuit to consume 10 T states instead of performing 10 T gates by using gate teleportation; it's just tedious to write that out.

@Yunzhe Actually, having reread the reference, I can see why their phrasing confused you. They do state that [[n,k,d]] refers to a code. But if you actually follow the reference they give you see that there's no 10 qubit code; there's just a 4 qubit circuit wiht 10 T gates that's ultimately equivalent to mine.

It's really weird then that what Box 2 gives are all valid stabilizer codes (e.g. the [[15, 1, 3]] and the Bravyi-Haah) except for the $[[10, 2, 2]]$ one. The reference in the Box 2 is just the very first paper of the protocol and it's the first reference in my question.

It's understandable if the first paper didn't realize their protocol based on the four-qubit code is equivalent to a larger ten-qubit code, but  that doesn't mean the code doesn't exist.

@Yunzhe When a factory comes from a code with a transversal T gate, the physical T gates commute with each other (because they are on separate qubits and gates on separate qubits trivially commute). The T gates in the [[10,2,2]] factory don't commute with each other, and therefore they cannot be from a code with a transversal T gate. There is no code here, just a circuit identity.
